# OpenAI can't get program to start

Tags: python, sockets, openai-gym

Whenever I try to run the program on universe, I get this error where the sockets close. I don't know how to fix it and I have been messing around with it for ages. I am using the sample code given by openAI, but for some reason the flash game doesn't load up as it is supposed to. Any suggestions?

I am following the python code given by https://github.com/openai/universe by the way. Which is this:

```
import gym
import universe  # register the universe environments

env = gym.make('flashgames.DuskDrive-v0')
env.configure(remotes=1)  # automatically creates a local docker container
observation_n = env.reset()

while True:
  action_n = [[('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True)] for ob in observation_n]  # your agent here
  observation_n, reward_n, done_n, info = env.step(action_n)
  env.render()
```

And this was the error log that I got when I tried to run it. I'm not exactly sure what's wrong and how to fix it.

```
[2017-10-05 00:29:24,424] Making new env: flashgames.DuskDrive-v0
[2017-10-05 00:29:24,453] Writing logs to file: /tmp/universe-29460.log
[2017-10-05 00:29:24,565] Ports used: [5900, 15900]
[2017-10-05 00:29:24,566] [0] Creating container: image=quay.io/openai/universe.flashgames:0.20.28. Run the same thing by hand as: docker run -p 5901:5900 -p 15901:15900 --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --ipc host --privileged quay.io/openai/universe.flashgames:0.20.28
[2017-10-05 00:29:27,287] Remote closed: address=localhost:15901
[2017-10-05 00:29:27,287] Remote closed: address=localhost:5901
[2017-10-05 00:29:27,288] At least one sockets was closed by the remote. Sleeping 1s...
universe-YJfaJs-0 | Setting VNC and rewarder password: openai
[2017-10-05 00:29:28,289] Remote closed: address=localhost:15901
[2017-10-05 00:29:28,290] Remote closed: address=localhost:5901
[2017-10-05 00:29:28,290] At least one sockets was closed by the remote. Sleeping 1s...
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [Wed Oct  4 13:29:28 UTC 2017] Waiting for /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 to be created (try 1/10)
[2017-10-05 00:29:29,292] Remote closed: address=localhost:5901
[2017-10-05 00:29:29,292] Remote closed: address=localhost:15901
[2017-10-05 00:29:29,299] At least one sockets was closed by the remote. Sleeping 1s...
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [Wed Oct  4 13:29:29 UTC 2017] [/usr/local/bin/sudoable-env-setup] Disabling outbound network traffic for none
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] 
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Xvnc TigerVNC 1.7.0 - built Sep  8 2016 10:39:22
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Copyright (C) 1999-2016 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Underlying X server release 11400000, The X.Org Foundation
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] 
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension VNC-EXTENSION
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Initializing built-in extension GLX
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] 
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Wed Oct  4 13:29:29 2017
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc]  vncext:      VNC extension running!
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc]  vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5900
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc]  vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [init] [2017-10-04 13:29:29,678] Launching system_diagnostics_logger.py, recorder_logdir=/tmp/demo
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [init] [2017-10-04 13:29:29,741] Launching reward_recorder.py, recorder_logdir=/tmp/demo
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [init] [2017-10-04 13:29:29,778] Launching vnc_recorder.py, recorder_logdir=/tmp/demo
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [init] [2017-10-04 13:29:29,810] PID 52 launched with command ['sudo', '-H', '-u', 'nobody', 'DISPLAY=:0', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null', '/app/universe-envs/controlplane/bin/controlplane.py', '--rewarder-port=15901']
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] [dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/, removing from list!
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] [dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/, removing from list!
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] [dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/, removing from list!
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [init] [2017-10-04 13:29:30,032] init detected end of child process 15 with exit code 0, not killed by signal
[2017-10-05 00:29:30,299] Remote closed: address=localhost:15901
[2017-10-05 00:29:30,300] Remote closed: address=localhost:5901
[2017-10-05 00:29:30,300] At least one sockets was closed by the remote. Sleeping 1s...
[2017-10-05 00:29:31,301] Remote closed: address=localhost:15901
[2017-10-05 00:29:31,301] At least one sockets was closed by the remote. Sleeping 1s...
[2017-10-05 00:29:32,306] Remote closed: address=localhost:15901
[2017-10-05 00:29:32,325] At least one sockets was closed by the remote. Sleeping 1s...
[2017-10-05 00:29:33,327] Remote closed: address=localhost:15901
[2017-10-05 00:29:33,342] At least one sockets was closed by the remote. Sleeping 1s...
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] 
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Wed Oct  4 13:29:33 2017
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc]  Connections: accepted: 172.17.0.1::51814
[2017-10-05 00:29:34,344] Remote closed: address=localhost:15901
[2017-10-05 00:29:34,345] At least one sockets was closed by the remote. Sleeping 1s...
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] 
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Wed Oct  4 13:29:34 2017
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc]  Connections: closed: 172.17.0.1::51814 (Clean disconnection)
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc]  EncodeManager: Framebuffer updates: 0
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc]  EncodeManager:   Total: 0 rects, 0 pixels
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc]  EncodeManager:          0 B (1:-nan ratio)
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [init] [2017-10-04 13:29:34,889] init detected end of child process 55 with exit code 0, not killed by signal
[2017-10-05 00:29:35,346] Remote closed: address=localhost:15901
[2017-10-05 00:29:35,347] At least one sockets was closed by the remote. Sleeping 1s...
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [nginx] 2017/10/04 13:29:35 [error] 65#65: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:15901/", host: "127.0.0.1:10003"
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [nginx] 172.17.0.1 - openai [04/Oct/2017:13:29:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "-"
universe-YJfaJs-0 | WebSocket server settings:
universe-YJfaJs-0 |   - Listen on :5898
universe-YJfaJs-0 |   - Flash security policy server
universe-YJfaJs-0 |   - No SSL/TLS support (no cert file)
universe-YJfaJs-0 |   - proxying from :5898 to localhost:5900
[2017-10-05 00:29:36,348] Using the golang VNC implementation
[2017-10-05 00:29:36,348] Using VNCSession arguments: {'subsample_level': 2, 'start_timeout': 7, 'fine_quality_level': 50, 'encoding': 'tight'}. (Customize by running "env.configure(vnc_kwargs={...})"
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [nginx] 2017/10/04 13:29:36 [info] 65#65: *1 client 172.17.0.1 closed keepalive connection
[2017-10-05 00:29:36,370] [0] Connecting to environment: vnc://localhost:5901 password=openai. If desired, you can manually connect a VNC viewer, such as TurboVNC. Most environments provide a convenient in-browser VNC client: http://localhost:15901/viewer/?password=openai
2017/10/05 00:29:36 I1005 00:29:36.377669 29460 gymvnc.go:417] [0:localhost:5901] opening connection to VNC server
2017/10/05 00:29:36 I1005 00:29:36.529764 29460 gymvnc.go:550] [0:localhost:5901] connection established
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    env.render()
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] 
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc] Wed Oct  4 13:29:36 2017
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc]  Connections: accepted: 172.17.0.1::51852
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc]  SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc]  SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc]  VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [tigervnc]  VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian bgr888
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gym/core.py", line 150, in render
    return self._render(mode=mode, close=close)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gym/core.py", line 286, in _render
    return self.env.render(mode, close)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gym/core.py", line 150, in render
    return self._render(mode=mode, close=close)
  File "/home/jeremy/universe/universe/wrappers/render.py", line 52, in _render
    return self.env.render(mode=mode, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gym/core.py", line 150, in render
    return self._render(mode=mode, close=close)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gym/core.py", line 286, in _render
    return self.env.render(mode, close)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gym/core.py", line 150, in render
    return self._render(mode=mode, close=close)
  File "/home/jeremy/universe/universe/envs/vnc_env.py", line 552, in _render
    self.vnc_session.render(self.connection_names[0])
go_vncdriver.Error: /tmp/pip-build-ChEkRs/go-vncdriver/.build/src/github.com/openai/go-vncdriver/main.go:387: go_vncdriver was installed without OpenGL support. See https://github.com/openai/go-vncdriver for details on how debug.
[2017-10-05 00:29:36,882] Killing and removing container: id=22d8e98f604330565368471dafe71f2fc119ddd18f27901ec3dbdbbdaa46e64b
[2017-10-05 00:29:37,079] [0:localhost:5901] Waiting on rewarder: failed to complete WebSocket handshake. Retry in 1s (slept 0s/7s): connection was closed uncleanly (WebSocket connection upgrade failed (502 - BadGateway))
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [nginx] 2017/10/04 13:29:37 [error] 65#65: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:15901/", host: "localhost:15901"
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [nginx] 172.17.0.1 - openai [04/Oct/2017:13:29:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "AutobahnPython/17.9.3"
universe-YJfaJs-0 | [nginx] 2017/10/04 13:29:37 [info] 65#65: *3 client 172.17.0.1 closed keepalive connection
[2017-10-05 00:29:38,084] [0:localhost:5901] Waiting on rewarder: failed to complete WebSocket handshake. Retry in 3s (slept 1s/7s): connection was closed uncleanly (peer dropped the TCP connection without previous WebSocket closing handshake)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your console output is basically guiding you to the [go-vncdriver](https://github.com/openai/go-vncdriver) page.

```
go_vncdriver.Error: /tmp/pip-build-ChEkRs/go-vncdriver/.build/src/github.com/openai/go-vncdriver/main.go:387: 
go_vncdriver was installed without OpenGL support. 
See https://github.com/openai/go-vncdriver for details on how debug.
```

For erros that might come up after solving this one, you should always take a look at [solutions to common OpenAI problems](https://github.com/openai/universe/wiki/Solutions-to-common-problems).